# Clonezilla: weird error about destination being smaller, though disks are identical

Tags: hard-drive, boot, partitioning, clone, clonezilla

I want to clone a 1Tb disk which has some issues with the Win7 boot manager. I want to clone it so I can try some remedies on the cloned disk.

The destination disk is also a 1Tb, empty disk. (Though it's a newer one with the 4096b/sector Advanced Format).

There are no other disks connected.

My source HDD has 3 partitions (sdb1, sdb2, sdb3). The Windows boot/reserve, the windows system, and a data partition.

When I try to use a disk-to-disk, local disk clone, Partclone gives me the same error for each of the 3 partitions:
"Calculating bitmap... Please wait"
"Target partition is smaller than source."

I'm using the latest version of Clonezilla.
What is causing this problem?

Comment: Although the disk is listed as 1TB they will never be exactly that size. If the disks are not identical models then you have to contend with factors such as block size, sectors, total bytes available on disk etc. From your description, although the disks are "1TB", I have a feeling the disk capacity of the destination disk is smaller than the source.

Comment: So, if I could somehow reduce the partitions a little bit, it would be alright? 
The partclone errors already start at the first partition (the windows boot partition): "Target partition size(2 Mb) is smaller than the source (105Mb)."

Comment: Have you pre-partitioned the new disk? How are you using partclone? Try formatting the destination disk to remove any and all existing partitions...

Comment: Big Chris: 
* they were identical in size.
* partitioning did not help.

* I solved it though, but not with Clonezilla.
I tried several imaging programs, the only one that did work was the CloneDisk that came on Hiren's boot CD.